# Unity Software crash when I press play in the editor using Vuforia AR camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am using Mac OS 10.11.6 (thats the latest I can update due to my machine being late 2008 model).
After I create my Vuforia project using Unity and I press play in the Editor. Unity Crashes.
Any Solutions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone finding this, the problem is the Unity Hub not requesting the camera permissions. So to fix, do this:

1. Move the Unity Hub from the Applications to any other folder
2. Start the Unity Editor directly and open/create any project (At this point you should probably be asked to allow Unity to access the Accessibility features).
3. Start your project with the camera/webcam requirements (in my case it was a Vuforia project). You should now be prompted to give Unity access to the Camera.
4. Close Unity and move Unity Hub back to Application folder.

You should now be set. Not sure why this has not been officially fixed yet. 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem please let me know if you find the solution. As trouble shooting I thought that it wasn't recognizing a camera, but it defaults to the macs webcam. I built the actual game file and installed it. I had it work the first time around but after I edited it when it opens I get the AR camera's background colour or skybox default.

Edit: Try downgrading to unity 2018.4... if you are using the latest version it looks like you stumbled across a bug. 2018 is the latest stable version.

Comment: when downloading earlier version of unity. Iam facing troubles when I try to import vuforia package. After trying on several macbook pro Machines. I am wondering whether it could be the processing power on macbook pro is not enough? 8gb ram